# Problema ao executar uma função no Asp.net.core.webapi + postgresql + npgsql+dapper

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, dapper, npgsql

Estou com um uma Webapi em asp.net core, usando o postgresql como banco de dados. Dentro do postgresql, tenho a seguinte função:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION evento_distancia(
IN lat numeric,
IN lng numeric,
IN dist double precision)
RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, nome character varying, descricao character 
varying, ImgUrl character varying, longitude numeric, latitude numeric, 
situacao boolean, DataHora timestamp with time zone, distancia double 
precision) AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
RETURN QUERY

select  e.id, e.nome, e.descricao, e.img_url as ImgUrl, e.longitude, 
e.latitude, e.situacao, e.data_hora as DataHora, (
              6371 * acos(
               cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(e.latitude))
               * cos(radians(e.longitude) - radians(lng)) +
               sin(radians(lat)) * sin(radians(e.latitude))
              )
              ) AS "distance" 
    from public.evento e
    where (not(e.latitude is null) and not (e.longitude is null) and (
              6371 * acos(
               cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(e.latitude))
               * cos(radians(e.longitude) - radians(lng)) +
               sin(radians(lat)) * sin(radians(e.latitude))
              )
              ) < dist) order by "distance" asc;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.evento_distancia(numeric, numeric, double precision)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Tenho minha classe evento da seguinte forma:

```
public class Evento : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int IdUsuario {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public DateTime DataHora {get;set;}
    public int IdEndereco {get;set;}
    public double Longitude {get;set;}
    public double Latitude {get;set;}
    public string Descricao {get;set;}
    public string ImgUrl {get;set;}
    public Boolean Situacao {get;set;}
}
```

monto meu sql, por exemplo:

```
string sql = select * from evento_distancia(minha_latitude, minha_longitude, 
 minha_distancia)
```

instancio minha lista e recebo a execução da minha query, a qual traria diversos itens:

```
IEnumerable<Evento> eventos;
eventos = dbConnection.Query<Evento>(sql);
```

O seguinte erro aparece vindo do npgsql:

```
An exception of type 'Npgsql.PostgresException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
```

Alguém já se deparou com o erro ou tem ideia do que seja?

Comment: Pode ser um problema de tipo e formato (decimal com ponto x decimal co, na hora de passar os valores **minha_latitude** e **minha_longitude**, verifica se o formato dos números do C# e do Postgre estão batendo entre si.